# Added two stroke oil to my gas. Now what do I do?

Tags: chevrolet, fuel-system

I have a 1996 vortex engine.  I added marine two stroke oil to a full tank of gas in my truck.  Now it won't start.  I'm not sure what to do.

Can I save my engine and get the truck started?

What would you do to the 45 gallons or so of contaminated gasoline?

Do I need to replace all 8 spark plugs?

I had added approximately 1/2 gallon of two stroke marine mix to the full tank gas.

Comment: Do you live anywhere near a coastline or an inland/river marina?

Comment: You said you added 1/2 gallon of the marine mix ... is this gas/2S oil mix, or straight 1/2 gallon of 2S oil? 1/2 gallon of gas/oil mix would not have caused an issue in a large gas tank. Not sure why you would have dropped straight 2S oil into your truck in the first place if that's what you did?

Comment: When you turn the key does it make noise?  Is it a clicking or a cranking?  Does it sound like it is almost starting?  Has it started for a few seconds and then died?  It could be coincidental that it won't start at the same time you added two stroke oil.

Answer (score 5):

You now have a mixture of 1:100, while two stroke engines typically run a more fat 1:50 to 1:25.

The oil is made to be burned this way, it doesn't give much smoke and soot, especially at that low concentration. Your 4 stroke motor should run fine with this mixture, too. Remember, there are people out there which always add 2S oil to their diesel, and some to their gas "to clean the motor". They typically also use something in the order of 1:100 to 1:200.

2S oil easily solves in fuel, and typically, one first adds oil to the tank before filling it up with fuel. That's sufficient to mix both. But if the oil is added to the full tank, it may sink to the bottom, get sucked into the fuel lines, and clog the fuel system. The pure oil doesn't burn, but i guess it didn't find its way into the motor, yet.

So, my advise is to flush the entire fuel system with fresh fuel (from the top of the tank, and to ensure the oil and fuel in the tank are mixed well. If possible, remove as much of the fuel as you can, and put it back into the tank. The movement of the fuel should be enough to mix it with the oil.